# How to create Hash with duplicate value count from JSON file

Tags: ruby

I have a JSON file being generated from my console and would like to parse it in order to see how many nodes I have running on what version and on which operating system.

Example JSON:

```json
[
 {
 "facts.aio_agent_version": "7.9.0",
 "facts.operatingsystem": "windows"
 },
 {
 "facts.aio_agent_version": "7.8.0",
 "facts.operatingsystem": "windows"
 },
 {
 "facts.aio_agent_version": "7.9.0",
 "facts.operatingsystem": "CentOS"
 },
 {
 "facts.aio_agent_version": "7.9.0",
 "facts.operatingsystem": "CentOS"
 },
 {
 "facts.aio_agent_version": "7.8.0",
 "facts.operatingsystem": "CentOS"
 }
]
```

I need an output of a ruby hash:

```
{"CentOS"=>"7.8.0"=>"nodes"=> 1, "CentOS"=>"7.9.0"=>"nodes"=> 2, "windows"=>"7.8.0"=>"nodes"=> 1, "windows"=>"7.9.0"=>"nodes"=> 1}
```

This is as far as I've managed to get:

```ruby
require 'json'

file = File.read('./data.json')


hash = JSON.parse(file)

hash2 = {}

hash.each { |key| 
    if !hash2.key?(key["facts.operatingsystem"]=>key["facts.aio_agent_version"])

        hash2[key["facts.operatingsystem"]] = key["facts.aio_agent_version"] = "node"
    else
        hash2[key["facts.operatingsystem"]["facts.aio_agent_version"]["node"]] =+ 1

    end
}

puts hash2
```

output:

```
{"windows"=>"node", "CentOS"=>"node"}
```

Comment: That  doesn't look like a valid Ruby hash, can you corroborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json = File.read('./data.json')
array = JSON.parse(json)
result = {}
array.each do |hash|
  os = hash['facts.operatingsystem']
  version = hash['facts.aio_agent_version']
  count = result.dig(os, version, 'nodes')
  if count
    result[os][version]['nodes'] = count + 1
  else
    result[os] = { version => { 'nodes' => 1 } }.merge(result[os] || {})
  end
end

puts result
```

for every hash in the array, we dig into our results hash to determine if we previously saw a node.  if we did, we increment the count. if we didn't  we create the node in the results hash. since an os can have many versions, we merge the existing nodes with the newly created node.

Comment: This is what I was exactly looking for, thank you! I'm new to Ruby so had a bit of an issue understanding how the hash's work.